# Swift 3 labels move by touch

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, label, uigesturerecognizer

Multiple labels, I want to move by touch
I just want you to move in the view I created

```
enter code here
@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!



override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.cardView)
        print(position.x, position.y)
        label.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:position.x-60,y:position.y-30)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what your question is :(

Comment: This code works, but I want to do more than one label, so it only works for label1

Comment: create an array of labels and loop through them? or loop through the subviews in the view containing the label eg. `for label in parentView.subviews { // do your things}`

Answer (score 1):

for moving labels within its superview you can add UIPanGestureRecognizer to label. 
For Example

```
func setGesture() -> UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector("handlePan:"))
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    return panGesture
}
//set the recognize in multiple views
lbl1.addGestureRecognizer(setGesture())
lbl2.addGestureRecognizer(setGesture())
```

Answer (score 0):

For moving objects with a finger, it is enough to override `touchesMoved` method. The thing you have missed in your example is that you should distruct  `previousLocation` from current `location`. Here is a sample code:

```
class MovableView: UIView {

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let oldLocation = touches.first?.previousLocation(in: self)
        let newLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
        move(with: CGPoint(x: (newLocation?.x)! - (oldLocation?.x)!, y: (newLocation?.y)! - (oldLocation?.y)!))

    }

    private func move(with offset: CGPoint) {
        center = CGPoint(x: center.x + offset.x, y: center.y + offset.y)
    }

}
```